# Wait for asynchronous function to finish before proceeding

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I want a variable to be assigned a value which comes from a asynchronous functions callback before it continues to next function/line of code.

In my jsfiddle it's the title variables that I want to get the value of the Soundcloud track API request. Hope you see what I mean, otherwise I'll come back to explain further.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ffj7x0be/16/)

I recently began understanding how asynchronous functions work, so I understand why my code doesn't really work. What I'm searching for is a way to make variable playerData wait to be run until the titles are assigned.

If that's not possible I'd be grateful for other tips on how to get this to work as I want.

Thanks!

Ps. In my real page every "player" div will contain players with different artists.

Relevant javascript from my jsfiddle where the commented lines is how I would have put it if it wasn't for the async problems:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var source = document.getElementById( 'player-template' ).innerHTML;
var playerTemplate = Handlebars.compile( source );

SC.initialize({
  client_id: '90fb9e15c1e26f39b63f57015ab8da0d'
});


var title1;
var title2;

  SC.get("/users/theshins/tracks", function(tracks){
  SC.oEmbed(tracks[0].permalink_url + "/&maxheight=100&maxwidth=300&format=json&sharing=false", document.getElementById('player1'));
      //title1 = tracks[0].title;
  });
  SC.get("/users/theshins/tracks", function(tracks){
  SC.oEmbed(tracks[0].permalink_url + "/&maxheight=100&maxwidth=300&format=json&sharing=false", document.getElementById('player2'));
      //title2 = tracks[0].title;
  });
  SC.get("/users/theshins/tracks", function(tracks){
  SC.oEmbed(tracks[0].permalink_url + "/&maxheight=100&maxwidth=300&format=json&sharing=false", document.getElementById('player3'));
  });
  SC.get("/users/theshins/tracks", function(tracks){
  SC.oEmbed(tracks[0].permalink_url + "/&maxheight=100&maxwidth=300&format=json&sharing=false", document.getElementById('player4'));
  });
  SC.get("/users/theshins/tracks", function(tracks){
  SC.oEmbed(tracks[0].permalink_url + "/&maxheight=100&maxwidth=300&format=json&sharing=false", document.getElementById('player5'));
  });
  SC.get("/users/theshins/tracks", function(tracks){
  SC.oEmbed(tracks[0].permalink_url + "/&maxheight=100&maxwidth=300&format=json&sharing=false", document.getElementById('player6' ));
  });


//Data that will replace the handlebars expressions in our template
var playerData = {
    title1 : title1,
    title2 : title2,
};

$('#player-placeholder').html(playerTemplate(playerData));

});
```

Comment: so you don't want those task being async?

Comment: Is that even possible? As I said in my first post and what I guess is more achievable is to wait for the playerData assignment to run until the title varibles are assigned (wait until they're != null, maybe?).

Comment: that's may be a solution and could work for you.

Comment: to make them sync instead of async? Hmm, if that's an easier solution it might be interesting, you got an example of it?

Answer (score 2):

With jQuery alone you would chain the promises of each request with the `$.when` function like so:

```
var a = $.get("/a");
var b = $.get("/b");
var c = $.get("/c");

$.when(a, b, c).then(function() {
   // render template here
});
```

I doubt that the soundcloud API returns jQuery promises, but I guess you can wrap the `SC.get` function to return jQuery promises:

```
function wrapGet(url) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    SC.get(url, function(result) {
        deferred.resolve(result);
    });
    return deferred.promise();
}
```

Now you can call it like this:

```
var a = wrapGet("/users/theshins/tracks").then(function(tracks){
  SC.oEmbed(tracks[0].permalink_url + "/&maxheight=100&maxwidth=300&format=json&sharing=false", document.getElementById('player1'));
      //title1 = tracks[0].title;
  });

var b = ...


$.when(a, b, ...).then(function() {
   // render template here
});
```

Comment: I've had problems with putting the playerData variable inside functions before, but I will definitely try this out!

Comment: Tried applying it like this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ffj7x0be/17/). Don't know exactly what and where it went wrong (possible to debug/troubleshoot through jsfiddle?). It can very likely be just me misunderstanding and applying it wrong.

Comment: This is just a concept, nothing I've actually tried. Yes, might be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to wait until those task being executed I recommend you to use some promise framework like this https://github.com/kriskowal/q